# React Native app with expo, console show a warning

Tags: react-native

Im working with React Native and using Expo. When I open the console from the browser I see that the app is using ReactDOM.render instead of createRoot to display the app. I wonder how can I change it from index.js or what can I do?
Thanks in advance.

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Hello, why are you trying to access console from browser with React Native?

Add further details to your questions

Comment: Hi there, No, I'm not trying to access the console from the browser. What I'm trying to say is console from the browser show the above warning, just when you open devTools from Chrome

Comment: Did you check the steps described on the provided link? https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot

Comment: I'm using React Native, I realized that warning is because I was render my app in the web but when I rendered my app in an android emulator the warning was gone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some changes in you index.js (if you have not changed the name) search for the latest syntax of react and there you will find what is wrong.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
 </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

if you have like this,
make it like this

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
 </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

Comment: Thanks but I realized that warning was because I was rendering my app in the web and not in an android device or emulator